# Attributes do not appear in tab for configuration

Tags: android, xml, attributes

Good evening friends in the community, I'm new here, and new to programming for Android, and I have a problem: After I installed Android Studio and started my first steps in learning, I noticed that the "Attributes" tab does not contain all the items needed to make changes, how do I make all items appear?

Unfortunately, the little I managed to do was add a few attributes through the XML, but as I'm a beginner, it's difficult.......

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.